# How to deal with overfitting with simple (X,Y) data in MLPRegressor

Tags: neural-network, perceptron, gridsearchcv

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj5F0.png)
[Result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B019b.png)
Solved

**Dealing with low amounts of data, and dealing with overfitting w/ Folding[GridSearchCV]**

I am completely stumped as to how to get better estimations from my model. It seems that when I try to run my code, I get negative Accuracies. How can I improve cross_val_score or testing scores or whatever you want to call it such that I can predict values more reliably.

I tried adding more data (from 50 to 200+).

I tried random parameters (and realized this was a Naive approach)

I also tried cleaning my data w/ StandardScaler on the features

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn import preprocessing
import requests
import json
from calendar import monthrange
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale


r =requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY_ADJUSTED&symbol=W&apikey=QYQ2D6URDOKNUGF4')

#print(r.text)

y = json.loads(r.text)
#print(y["Monthly Adjusted Time Series"].keys())

keysInResultSet = y["Weekly Adjusted Time Series"].keys()
#print(keysInResultSet)

featuresListTemp = []
labelsListTemp = []

count = 0;

for i in keysInResultSet: 
    #print(i)
    count = count + 1;
    #print(y["Monthly Adjusted Time Series"][i])
    tmpList = []
    tmpList.append(count)
    featuresListTemp.append(tmpList)
    strValue = y["Weekly Adjusted Time Series"][i]["5. adjusted close"]
    numValue = float(strValue)
    labelsListTemp.append(numValue)


print("TOTAL SET")
print(featuresListTemp)
print(labelsListTemp)
print("---")

arrTestInput = []
arrTestOutput = []


print("SCALING SET")
X_train = np.array(featuresListTemp)
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train)

X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
print(X_train_scaled)


product_model = MLPRegressor()
#10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 10)

#todo : once found general settings, iterate through some more seeds to find one that can be used on the training

parameters = {'learning_rate': ['constant','adaptive'],'solver': ['lbfgs','adam'], 'tol' : 10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 4), 'verbose' : [True], 'early_stopping': [True], 'activation' : ['tanh','logistic'], 'learning_rate_init': 10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 4), 'max_iter': [4000], 'alpha': 10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 4), 'hidden_layer_sizes':np.arange(1,11), 'random_state':np.arange(1, 3)}
clf = GridSearchCV(product_model, parameters, n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(X_train_scaled, labelsListTemp)
print(clf.score(X_train_scaled, labelsListTemp))
print(clf.best_params_)

best_params = clf.best_params_


newPM = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=((best_params['hidden_layer_sizes'])), #try reducing the layer size / increasing it and playing around with resultFit variable
                                     batch_size='auto',
                                     power_t=0.5,
                                     activation=best_params['activation'],
                                     solver=best_params['solver'], #non scaled input
                                     learning_rate=best_params['learning_rate'],
                                     max_iter=best_params['max_iter'],
                                     learning_rate_init=best_params['learning_rate_init'],
                                     alpha=best_params['alpha'],
                                     random_state=best_params['random_state'],
                                     early_stopping=best_params['early_stopping'],
                                     tol=best_params['tol'])

scores = cross_val_score(newPM, X_train_scaled, labelsListTemp, cv=10, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))

print(scores)
```

Output from line 63 and down

> 0.9142644531564619 {'activation': 'logistic', 'alpha': 0.001, 'early_stopping': True, 'hidden_layer_sizes': 7, 'learning_rate':
>   'constant', 'learning_rate_init': 0.1, 'max_iter': 4000,
>   'random_state': 2, 'solver': 'lbfgs', 'tol': 0.01, 'verbose': True}
>
> Accuracy: -21.91 (+/- 58.89) [ -32.87854574 -105.0632913
>   -22.89836453   -7.33154414  -22.38773819    -3.3786339    -1.7658796    -3.78002866   -4.78734308  -14.81212738]

Answer (score 0):

{'activation': 'logistic', 'alpha': 0.01, 'early_stopping': True, 'hidden_layer_sizes': 30, 'learning_rate': 'constant', 'learning_rate_init': 0.1, 'max_iter': 4000, 'random_state': 2, 'solver': 'lbfgs', 'tol': 0.1, 'verbose': True}

{'activation': 'tanh', 'alpha': 0.01, 'early_stopping': True, 'hidden_layer_sizes': 99, 'learning_rate': 'constant', 'learning_rate_init': 0.1, 'max_iter': 4000, 'random_state': 1, 'solver': 'lbfgs', 'tol': 0.01, 'verbose': True}

Both configurations stated above will work for the sample set. Thanks all, please let me know if there are any questions. This can be solved by scaling down all your other parameters ie. instead of 10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 3) do 10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 2)

to a more limited set. Start removing parameters that you know are correct (very hard to do, but one could be learning_rate='constant' as I noticed that all my best fits resulted in a learning rate that was constant, regardless of any other parameters.

This is mostly for time optimization but will also help with overfitting as you increase the number of nodes in the network. The idea is that you want to increase the fit some N degrees without losing too much of the generalization properties of the true function) once you perform your first grid search.

You should start you grid search making sure that the # of hidden nodes is some where between the # of input nodes and the # of output nodes.

Once you find a decent fit, you can improve the fit by increasing the number of nodes. You must take care not to add too many nodes as to lose the generalization power of the true function. Before you even start thinking about scaling up, you must start reducing the complexity of the parameters such that on your second grid search you will be performing it on an increased number of nodes w/ more general parameters.

The generalization of parameters is described above with the second grid search taking into account more general parameters from the initial search, whilst increasing the network nodes.

I know this is confusing but it's what helped me fit this decently.

For anyone struggling I would try to 
0) generalize after performing a search and getting a decent model
1) use generalization on second search with increased nodes
2) play with alpha parameter while scaling up (the rest of the parameters you can generalize)
3) add a few different seeds or remove them depending on the situation
4) While changing tol will alter fit it is also highly dependent on the number of iterations. For that reason, depending on the case, a reasonable number might be .01 or .001 (reasonable depending on how many iterations you want to wait for a given result/ opportunity to converge) If the tol is set too low, you will run out of iterations as each epoch will never get a chance to stop early.